# MySQL - Get Max usingSubquery on same table

Tags: mysql, date

I have the following query, which gets me the total reading for a particular day, with a sub-query that doesn't work (returns *null*)

```
SELECT (max(value)-min(value)) as used, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(`tsr`, '%d %b %Y %k %m') as ndate,
       (SELECT min(value) 
        FROM `readings` 
        WHERE channel_id = '1' 
        AND property = 'energy_active_sum' 
        AND delta = '0' 
        AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(tsr) = ndate + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        ORDER BY tsr ASC 
        LIMIT 1) as lRead
FROM readings 
WHERE channel_id = '1' 
AND property = 'energy_active_sum' 
AND delta = '0' 
AND ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(tsr) >= '" . $graphStart . "') 
AND (FROM_UNIXTIME(tsr) <= '" . $graphEnd . " 23:59:59') ) 
GROUP BY ndate 
ORDER BY tsr ASC
```

*$graphStart* = defined date by user, i.e. 2017-08-21

*$graphEnd* = defined date by user, i.e. 2017-08-24

This will then output this ideally:

```
used    date            lRead
------------------------------
473.5   21 Aug 2017     45698
427.5   22 Aug 2017     46129
422     23 Aug 2017     46556
198.5   24 Aug 2017     null    (as data for the 25th doesn't exist yet)
```

The reason for the sub-query is that the *value* is a whole reading that is entered into the database at 10 past the hour. So just using the first query would only give me the *max* until 23:10, missing 50 minutes.
The next reading comes in at 00:10, which is the next day (so the 25th if using today as an example). 
The sub-query is my attempt to get that one reading.

I've tried different variations, and cannot get it to return the reading.
Ideally it would get the reading and use it as *max* rather than just as another column.

I am hoping this makes sense, if not please comment and I will hopefully be able to clear things up based on the questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi Seán, can you post some sample data? This might help me make sense of your query more easily.